# Make an accordion stay open when reloading a page (Wordpress - Visual Composer)

Tags: wordpress, accordion

Here's the page I'm referring to: https://columbuspre-school.com/admissions-new/

I've built a long Gravity Form into an accordion near the top of the page, by default I've made the accordion closed when loading the page (because the form takes up a lot of room).

However, if a user tries to submit the form without a required field, the page reloads, and because the accordion loads closed - the user can't see the text stating there was a problem with the submission.

How can I make it so that when the page reloads the accordion stays in the same state (open)?

Answer (score 0):

Your form adds 'gform_validation_error' class if it encounters an error and you can use its existence to trigger accordion.

Add custom jquery to your theme and do something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

if ( $('.accordion_wrapper').hasClass('gform_validation_error') ){//check if error class exits

$('.accordion_wrapper .title').click(); // simulate click event to open accordion

console.log( "triggered!" );

}

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try that - what file should I add that to? functions.php?

Comment: I guess you are using betheme which lets you add custom jquery in its backend theme panel.

Comment: Be careful about the jquery selector, use 'jQuery' instead of '$' in case it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, I'm pretty new to jQuery - can you expand on what you mean by using 'jQuery' instead of '$' in case it doesn't work?

Comment: Your theme may allow you to use 'jQuery' selector instead of '$' if it has put on '$.no conflict' mode for the custom js. More info is @ https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Let me know, if you were able to get it done or pm me wp admin credentials @ aaronter[at]gmail.com to get the job done for you.

Comment: I tried pasting your code exactly as it is above in the custom jQuery area, as well as pasting it will all instances of "$" replaced with "jQuery", am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154257/discussion-between-arun-sharma-and-andrewcoco).